# Getting value into input textfield

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
**reg.html** 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reg.css"> </link>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="reg.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<!--container start-->
<div id="container">
  <div id="container_body">
    <div>
      <h2 class="form_title">Registration Form Demo</h2>
      <p class="head_para">Form Validation   Using Javascript</p>
    </div>
    <!--Form  start-->
    <div id="form_name">
      <div class="firstnameorlastname">
       <form name="form" method="get" >

        <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="First Name"  class="input_name" required>
        <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="input_name" required >

      </div>
      <div id="email_form">
        <input type="text" name="Email" value=""  placeholder="Your Email" class="input_email" >
      </div>
      <div id="mobileno_form">
        <input type="number" name="Mobileno" value=""  placeholder="Mobile No" class="input_mobileno" maxlength="10" required>
      </div>
      <div id="city_form">
        <input type="text" name="City" value=""  placeholder="Choose City" class="input_city" >

         <input type="button" onClick='window.open("regtable.html","Ratting","width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,");' value="Show City">
      </div>
      <div id="state_form">
        <input type="text" name="State" value=""  placeholder="State" class="input_state">
      </div>
     <div id="errorBox"></div>
       <div>
        <p id="sign_user" onClick="Submit()">Submit </p>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    <!--form ends-->
  </div>
</div>
<!--container ends-->
</body>
</html>


**reg.js**

function Submit(){
 var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
 var mobilenoex = [0-9];
 var fname = document.form.Name.value,
  lname = document.form.LastName.value,
  femail = document.form.Email.value,
  fmobileno = document.form.Mobileno.value;


 if( fname == "" )
   {
     document.form.Name.focus() ;
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
     return false;
   }
 if( lname == "" )
   {
     document.form.LastName.focus() ;
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
     return false;
   }

   if (femail == "" )
 {
  document.form.Email.focus() ;
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the email";
  return false;
  }else if(!emailRegex.test(femail)){
  document.form.Email.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid email";
  return false;
  }


 if(fmobileno == "")
  {
   document.form.Mobileno.focus();
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the Mobile no";
   return false;
  }else if(!mobilenoex.test(fmobileno)){
  document.form.Mobileno.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid mobileno";
  return false;
  }

  if(fname != '' && lname != '' && femail != '' && fmobileno != '' ){
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
   }

}


**regtable.html**


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postvalue(id){
                alert(this.value);
            document.form.City.value = document.frm.c_name.value;
            }
        </script>
        <title>Choose your Cities</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form name="frm">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr id="1">
                            <td><input type="radio" name="c_name" class="rbox"  onClick="postvalue();" value="Hyderabad" />Hyderabad</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="2">
                            <td><input type="radio" name="c_name" class="rbox" onClick="postvalue();" value="Vizag"/> Vizag</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="3">
                            <td><input type="radio" name="c_name" class="rbox" onClick="postvalue();" value="warangal"/>warangal</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="4">
                            <td><input type="radio" name="c_name" class="rbox" onClick="postvalue();" value="Secunderabad"/>Secunderabad</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>



**reg.css**


*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 }
body{
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 }
#container{
 width:550px;
 background-color:rgba(250,250,252,.9);
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:160px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 box-shadow:0 0 3px #999;
 }
#container_body{
 padding:20px 10px 20px 10px;
 }
.form_title{
 font-size:35px;
 color:#141823;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
 font-weight:normal;
 }
.head_para{
 font-size:19px;
 color:#99a2a7;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:normal;
 }
#form_name{
 padding:25px 0 0 15px;
 }
.firstnameorlastname{
  margin-right:20px;
 }
.input_name{
 width:207px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
#email_form{
 clear:both;
 padding:15px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_email{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
#mobileno_form{
 padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_mobileno{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;

 }
 #city_form{
 padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_city{
 width:334px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
 #state_form{
 padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_state{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
 .input_button{
     width: 70px;
      padding:10px;
      font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 }
select{
 padding:5px;
 }
#sign_user{
 font-size:14px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#3B5998;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
#errorBox{
 color:#F00;
 }
```

In the reg.html, by clicking on "Show city" button , regtable.html will be opened In that on selecting one of the cities radio button i have to get updated the city name in reg.html page city text field. I am unable get this done. Can anyone help me? i need this to be done using HTML,CSS and Javascript.

Comment: are these two pages in same view?

Comment: not in the same view.

Answer (score 0):

In the page where you give options to choose city, you have a javascript function to update the city value. This function updates the value in parent window, not in the same one. Then you can close the window. So you need to modify your function like this -

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        function postvalue(){
            window.opener.document.form.City.value = document.frm.c_name.value;
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: yes, it does  work. You have to put this script in regtable.html file. Replace your function with this one.